# Why not to include reference to /wp-admin/admin.php in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-contact-form-7

Contact Form 7 recently pushed out an update which caused a few conflicts in other plugins. WPCF7 Author explains that it's because plugins are including calls to `wp-admin/admin.php` in their scripts which you shouldn't do in a plugin. [Takayuki Miyoshi](https://ideasilo.wordpress.com/) explains it [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-class-wpcf7_taggenerator-not-found-3) but I'm not sure I understand exactly *why* it would cause any kind of issue or how this is different from calling say `wp-load.php`.

Could somebody explain why it's advised never to load `wp-admin/admin.php` in your plugin and how it could cause issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could somebody explain why it's advised never to load
>   wp-admin/admin.php in your plugin and how it could cause issues?

Because it is loading WordPress out of context-- well, parts of WordPress. And that can cause unexpected effects such as functions not being loaded or functions being loaded twice (which will cause fatal errors). You will have trouble with hooks firing multiple times, or not firing. You may have trouble with constants. You may not have trouble, but that depends upon how and why the files are loaded.

> ...how this is different from calling say `wp-load.php`[?]

`wp-load.php` is a bootstrap file that `admin.php` will load about line thirty-something. It is a similar hack and can have similar problems. It should not be done either.

There is very little reason to use either technique. WordPress should be loaded for you plugin for most purposes and if not, say you need to make a separate request, use the [AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) which will boot WordPress properly.

Comment: I kind of understand that, but if including it in a plugin could cause fatal errors ( duplicate functions ) wouldn't it happen immediately as soon as it's included and white-screen the website? How could including it in one plugin effect a separate plugin?

Comment: It depends on how and where and why the code loads. If a plugin is enabled, a lot of its code loads too.  That can cause problems immediately or, if say there is a require inside a function, it might only cause trouble intermittently.